# Is this image of Jean-Luc Picard sourced from a TNG episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, image-identification

I recently played *Star Trek: The Next Generation: Echoes from the Past*, and was greeted by the following image of a front-facing Picard on several screens:

[image: Image of Picard facing the player.]

I at first assumed that the image was hand-drawn pixel art, made from scratch for the game, but according to Memory Alpha's [page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_-_Future%27s_Past#Background_information) on *Future's Past*, another release of the same game, many visual assets used were traced from TNG:

[image: Images from Star Trek: Future's Past and their sources.]

As someone researching this game, I would appreciate any leads on the source of this image.

Comment: That's not a picture of anyone's face.  It might be generated from an image of Patrick Stewart, but it appears to be vertically symmetric (before colouring), so not an actual photo.

Comment: I want to say there was a poster or VHS cover or something that was half of Picard's face in shadow like that. I'm guessing they mirrored that.

Comment: it appears to be taken either from generations movie poster or from First contact movie poster.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations#/media/File:S07-Star_Trek_Generations-poster_art.png First contact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact#/media/File:Star_trek_first_contact_poster.jpg

Comment: Certainly not First Contact @jo1storm since the game in question was released in the same year as the Generations film :)

Comment: I'm curious why Worf's shirt changed colors in the game...

Comment: @TylerH - Worf only wore red in season 1. After he moved to Security, he wore gold. The game is set later in the Enterprise-D's adventures (see release date of 1994). Players would have been far more familiar w/ Worf being in gold than red. Also note game Troi is apparently post-Jellico (ie - regulation uniform and hair)

Comment: Worf's baldric is his later silver one as well

Comment: all images sourced for you now feeb :) - now, the question as to "why" only season 1 episodes were used....

Comment: @NKCampbell Plus the collars seem to be of the S3+ style. And *is* that Jellico in the last image? Doesn't look like Picard.

Comment: While we're pointing out differences, note that Riker has a beard in the game, but not in the episode that shot is from.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A possibility:

Based on the opening shot of Picard from the pilot episode "Encounter at Farpoint"

It obviously isn't an exact shot just pixelized (the perspective is a little different and he is wearing a post-S2 uniform with a higher collar in the pixel image), but appears very much based on said opening.

[image]

It could be the same image, and they just used the left side, then did a mirror image for the right side. His face almost appears  * too * wide and it is nearly exactly symmetrical

Here's a quick version I just made in Photoshop using the mirror image idea:

[image]
The starfield / Picard image is from Season 1 episode "Lonely Among Us"

[image]

The Dr. Crusher scene is from S1: The Battle

[image]

And finally, the conference room scene is from Season 1: The Neutral Zone

[image]

Comment: The left half looks the exact same, then the right half is just mirrored in the pixel art.
In all the other images there are slight differences as well, such as the yellow uniforms in the third set. With the shadow on the face this looks good, +1

Comment: @hammythepig - I was literally updating my answer with that exact comment and had clicked save and saw your comment below - just FYI :D

Comment: There was never doubt it was a mirrored image - but you've proven exactly the source of the image. Incidentally there was a TNG episode with a mirrored star field - but a search for it is proving more difficult than it is worth.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - updated w/ info re: the starfield - S1:E6

Comment: All of the pixel images are substantially wider than the video stills.  My guess, it's a native 4:3 game stretchy-squashy mangled to 16:9, then a screenshot taken.

Comment: @NKCampbell I salute your incredible efforts.  Just for the record my mirrored starfield comment is mere trivia about some episode that had a symmetric background starfield space scene and I think it was fixed on bluray.  Only related to this topic because symmetric faces and starfields both look wrong.

Comment: @fluffysheap You are correct. This is a common error when playing old PC games that used [non-square pixels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvckyWxHAIw) on modern hardware.

Comment: It's very clever the way the artist used blue and green so that we instantly see that it's totally symmetrical.